# Prevent $http service execution using Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http

I am building an authentication solution with Angular. I am using Interceptors to validate Request and if there is not valid token prevent from further processing and redirect.  Here is my simplified Interceptor:

```
prism.service('APIInterceptor', function($rootScope) {
var service = this;

service.request = function(config) { 
    .....
    return config;
  };
})
```

Just for the sake of  POC that I am working on what would the correct way of stopping this request from any further processing be?

Thanks

Comment: `return null;' will probably do it.

Comment: Yes, it will not go for data, but in the Console it says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null

Comment: Try printing out the config object, see what methods and fields are available within it. If you can't outright cancel the XHR request from initiating, perhaps you can just point it at an invalid URL. This will still throw a 404, but it shouldn't break anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Angular Docs on Interceptors for the `request` method:

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.

The rest of the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). From this you can see that the method can also return a promise (which is actually pretty awesome) so you could always reject it.

Try something like this:

```
prism.service('APIInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope) {
  this.request = function(config) {
    if( /*config is not valid*/ ) {
      return $q.reject({message: 'ERROR, ERROR... INTRUDER ALERT!', status: 401, config: config});
    } else {
      return config;
    }
  };
});
```

And see how it might be handled (I have no idea what your application will do). Let me know if it works out for you!

**EDIT:** My answer has been accepted, but is incomplete and it will haunt me forever if I don't complete it. So, after writing some test code of my own I've realized that you can do 1 of 2 things in this situation. The first is to handle the unauthorized request in the interceptor:

```
...
this.request = function(config) {
  if(/* config is not authorized */) {
    // Do something here like redirect/issue another request... whatever
    return $q.reject({/*whatever the hell you want*/});
  } else ...
};
...
```

This obviously works best if you want to handle all unauthorized requests the same. If you don't, however, the second option is to defer to the service that issued the request. For example, if you're using `$http` you can do this:

```
$http.get('/words/words/words/').then(function(){
  // This is where you handle a successful request.
}, function(error) {
  // Handle your error here. Please take note that this error message is
  // whatever you sent back in the `reject` previously
});
```

Hopefully that clears a few things up.

Comment: I tried to return your code. The processing was stopped, but I did not see any alert messages if that is what you were expecting.

Comment: The message is probably returned to the `$http.get('.../someroute/').error(function(error){});` callback. However, if your plan of action when authorization fails is application wide, you can write whatever logic you want in that conditional to either redirect/notify other services without having to deal with the error you were getting. If your plan of action differs on a per-request basis, you should try the `error` callback

Comment: Well, it returns to response = response.then(function (data) {
            return data.data;
        }); It would be nice to return back to response.catch(function (data) {
            $q.reject(data);
        });